# how do i Update data on my android app after launching on google play?

Tags: android

How do I update my app data once I have already add it to google play store ?
I am creating an android app for my college and it needs to be constantly updated after being launched on the play store.

Comment: I need to change notices and add new events, do I need a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either publish a new version of the app or write it in such a way that it fetches the data from an external server (for example via a web service).

Comment: Is there any alternative for using a server ?

Comment: Yes, publish a new version of the app whenever there is a change. However, it will take about a day or two until all users get the update.

Comment: Can google app engine be used or Should I use JSON ?